# How to store the_title() into a variable to reutrn the value, not just echo it

Tags: php, functions, array, variables

I have a loop, and need to pass one more argument through it. I need to get the current page's single post title, and then use that as the value.

I tried going about it like this:

```
$tagz = the_title();

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'product_tag' => "{$tagz}"  );
```

and the `$tagz` variable just automatically echo's the current post title. I found out through this resource [this resource](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) that `the_title()` merely echos the title and never returns it, making the `$tagz` variable null.

How can I use the current posts title as an argument? I am really stumped!!

Comment: Did you try `$tagz = the_title( ''. '', 0 );` ?

Comment: Submit that as the answer and I'll mark you correct :D

I used `$tagz = the_title( ''. '', false );`

but it's the same thing, and it worked!!!!!!!

I reread the resource I linked, and now I understand it better because of you. I just started learning php last month, thank you so much :D you've made an impact on my life, stranger!

Comment: I'm sure we can find a duplicate question and vote for it and the corresponding answers instead ;-) Glad to hear it worked for you and welcome to the communitiy by the way ;-)

Comment: Sounds good :) is there a specific way to search for a duplicate question? :o

Comment: Maybe with [is:question the_title return post title](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+the_title+return+post+title) or some variants?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post Title displaying but not in the wrapped HTML I need](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30739/post-title-displaying-but-not-in-the-wrapped-html-i-need)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) to return the current post title in the loop.

Comment: Just remember, `get_the_title` is unfiltered

Comment: get_the_title's output is filtered using 'the_title' - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L158